# Downloading wsdl file in professional edition getting error " Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access... "

Tags: wsdl

While downloading wsdl file in professional edition getting error 
"Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary."
We have created a System Administrator account in our client's salesforce professional edition ,gave "Modify All Data" permission to it , still its not working.

Comment: Which wsdl you are trying? Because professional edition do not have api acccess https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005140

Answer (score 0):

To use the APIs you need them to be enabled.

Some editions come with API Access - See [Salesforce editions with API Access](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005140).

By default a professional edition org doesn't have API access, but it can be purchased as an add-on by contacting your Account Executive.

Once you do have the API enabled, you also need the "API Enabled" Administrative Permission.